# Do gas cooktops result in more greasy residue than induction?

Tags: induction, gas

I have a problem with greasy residue (the bane of my existence) in my kitchen. It builds up pretty quickly on most surfaces close to the cooktop, makes dust stick, and is a horrible tedium to clean up.

Is this common?

My suspicion is that it's either my ventilation, my cooking habits, or the type of cooktop that causes this.

Ventilation is hard to change, but what I do have is not the filter-only type but one that leads the air to the outside. Likewise, my cooking habits are hard to change - I want to keep on cooking close to the smokepoint etc.

Can this problem be mitigated by switching to induction or am I stuck with having to clean greasy surfaces for the rest of my life?

Comment: Very, very closely related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/117700

Comment: Do you use a splatter screen?  (Which would not be in that other question that people are linking to, as it’s not talking about mitigation)

Comment: I agree this is a duplicate, the type of heat source is immaterial.

Comment: @rumtscho et. al definitely a duplicate, I guess I should have searched for aerosol and genesis instead of mundane words like greasy residue! Thanks for the help, I'll need to increase ventilation then.

Comment: @Max this is the main reason our sites don't delete duplicates, but just close them - it is pretty common that people use different terms for the same thing. Now there are two separate posts about the same thing, both of which can be found, and from both of them, a single coherent list of answers is reachable - quite useful for all the other people with the same problem who will find it later.